# Rails only allowing certain strings as a param

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 5.2.3 API that is being consumed by a Vue application I maintain.

In the API, I have a `Questions` table, and each `Question` has a specific `type`. I'm creating a feature where my users can create their own custom questions out of a select few options of question types, for the sake of simplicity let's say they only have 2 options to choose from, an `OpenEnded` question and a `StarRating` question.

While I realize the risk of bad user input here is impossible (since on the client side of things I'm just giving them a checklist and supplying that checklist to the API), I'd still like to have some checks in place to ensure that the *ONLY* `type` permitted in the params are `OpenEnded` and `StarRating`, especially since I'm planning on expanding this API to be public-facing at some point in the future, where the risk of bad input is indeed possible.

What's the proper way of handling this so that my API returns a `400` or `422` code if the question `type` isn't one of the whitelisted options?

The current `create` method and `question_params` method are about as bog-standard as they can possibly get

```rb
def create
  @question = Question.new(question_params)
  if @question.save
    render json: { question: @question }, status: :created
  else
    render json: { errors: @question.errors }, status: :bad_request
  end
end

def question_params
  params.permit(:content, :type)
end
```

Comment: Note that [`type` has a special meaning](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the proper way of handling this so that my API returns a 400 or 422 code if the question type isn't one of the whitelisted options?

You would do this as a [validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html). Simplest way is to do it on the Question model.

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  validates :type, inclusion: { in: %w(OpenEnded StarRating) }
end
```

The save will fail if the type is missing or incorrect.

Note that [type has a special meaning](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions), you may wish to consider a different column name if you're not using [Single Table Inheritance](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html).

Comment: AFAK rubocop complains at %w() => %w[..].

Comment: @razvans That's straight of the of the Rails Guides. rubocop has its opinions. Some of them are a bit fussy.

Comment: The column isn't actually called `type`, just was easier to understand than `kind`, but thanks for the heads up!